# What is the gravitational potential of a homogeneous sphere?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, newtonian-gravity, potential, integration

I am studying gravitational potentials from the book *Galactic Dynamics* by James Binney and Scott Tremaine. They provide the equation from where the potential of a spherical system is to be derived as:
$$\phi(r) = - 4\pi G \left(\frac{1}{r} \int_{0}^{r}\text{d}r'r'^2 \rho(r') + \int_{r}^{\infty} \text{d}r' r' \rho(r') \right)\tag{1}$$
From what I understand the first term is for a sphere with mass located inside the shell whose potential we are calculating whereas the latter is for a sphere of mass located outside the region whose potential is being calculated.
Now for a homogenous sphere the results given are:
$$\phi(r) = -2\pi G\rho \left(a^2-\frac{1}{3}r^2 \right)\tag{2}$$ for a region inside a sphere and $$\phi(r) = -\frac{4\pi G\rho a^3}{3r}\tag{3}$$ for a region outside the sphere.
While I understood the straightforward integration of the second one the first one confuses me as I have a limit going to infinity and an r in the numerator. How do I integrate that? Also I am not understanding how the factor of $1/3$ appears.

Comment: "While I understood the straightforward integration of the second one the first one confuses me as I have a limit going to infinity and an r in the numerator."  — Did you accidentally switch "the first one" and "the second one" in this sentence?

Comment: No. Look at my statement carefully. The first part of the first eqn actually coincides with the second part. Idk why it was written that way in the book but it is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gauss's theorem stipulates that:

$$\int^{}_{} \overrightarrow{F} .\overrightarrow{ds} \  =\  4\pi MG$$

On the surface of the planet of mass M and radius R and beyond ($r>R$), at a radius $r$, the Force of gravity is therefore:

$$F = - 4\pi MG/S = -4\pi MG/(4 \pi r^2 ) = MG/r^2 $$
and the correspondant potential:

$$ V(r) =  MG/r \tag{1}$$

if r < R, only the mass contained within the sphere of radius r contributes (the outer layer cancel out for symmetry reasons):

$$\int^{}_{} \overrightarrow{F} .\overrightarrow{ds} 
 = - 4\pi  M_{inside}.G$$

Therefore:

$$FS - = 4 \pi G \rho 4/3 \pi r^3$$

$$F 4 \pi r^2 = - 4 \pi G \rho 4/3 \pi r^3$$
$$ F =  4/3 \pi r G \rho \ $$

and the corresponding potential

$$ V_{inside}(r) =  - 2/3 \pi r^2 G \rho + constant $$

If one chooses the undetermined constant such that:

$$V_{inside}(0) = V(0)$$

Then

$$ constant = 2/3 \pi R^2 G \rho $$

and the final expression for V(r) becomes:

$$V(r) =  2/3 G \rho \pi ( R^2 - r^2)  $$

So, indeed the factor $1/3$ in: $()=−2(^2−1/3^2)$ appears to be a typo.

Answer (score 1):

For a homogeneous sphere of radius $a$: $$\rho(r)=\cases{\rho_0&if $\quad r<a$\\0&if $\quad r>a$},$$ so for a point at a distance $r<a$, the first integral in OP's Eq. $(1)$ goes up to $r$ but the second one stops at $a$ since there is no mass for $r'>a$

$$\int_r^\infty dr'r'\rho(r')=\int_r^adr'r'\rho_0.$$ With this, we get OP's Eq. $(2)$.